# Pycharm does not show if package is not import

Tags: python, pycharm

Maybe it's me did something wrong, my Pycharm cannot give underlines on questionable packages.

For example, if you create a python file from scratch and only put one line as below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
```

This will not give any red lines below 'pd' or give hitns on abc.csv that does not exist.

Is it some where in my Pycharm settings to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you didn't import anything that adds `pd` to the namespace, PyCharm would underline `pd` and the warning text would be `Unresolved reference 'pd'`. If you're not getting that, you must have disabled it, or you're entering this text into a file other than a Python source file (like a `.py`).

[image]

Open your `File - Settings...`, use the search to look for `inspection`, and in the `Inspections` section, look for the `Unresolved references` inspection in the `Python` and make sure that it is checked.

[image]